# jquery collapse button does not load remote content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a collapsible button which, after a click, fetches content from a URL and loads the results into the current page.

The button works fine when the href points to a location within the same page (href="#abcd"), but gives an error when href points to remote data (href="/query/abcd")

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /query/abcd

/query/abcd - runs a db query and returns an HTML table which should be rendered under the collapsible button

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>


<div class="container">
  <a href="/query/abcd" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse">Query results here - 10 items</a>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All this is going to do is redirect your site to whatever is located at /query/abcd...  so if you are on "http://www.foo.bar/somedir/somepage.html" it will redirect to "http://www.foo.bar/query/abcd".  Is that what you're trying to do?  Or is there more code to this than meets the eye here?  My gut feeling says we are looking at an incomplete picture here.....

Comment: I need the contents of foo.bar/query/abcd to load the same way if it was local data specified with a #abcd `<a href="#abcd" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse">Query results here - 10 items</a>
  <div id="abcd" class="collapse">
    quiery results here  
  </div>`

Comment: So what you're asking is when you click on the link, an ajax call fires off, goes and fetches the data, and then renders it out to your view.  Is /query/abcd going to return json?  HTML?  etc...  Either way the answer is similar.  In any case, please edit the question to clarify so the hold gets taken off of it.  Thanks!

Comment: I edited the question. hope it makes sense now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the remote content to load into a collapsible button with a little help from a javascript function:

I don't know if this is the best way but it seems to work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
 
  function load_results() {
      $('#abcd').text("Loading results... ");
      $('#abcd').load("/query/abcd");
      return false
  };
    
 </script>


</head>


<div class="container">
  <a href="#abcd" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" onclick="load_results()">Query results here - 10 items</a>
  <div id="abcd" class="collapse">
    test
  </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it with what you're doing, yes.

Comment: the only small problem with this is that the query is not cached on the page. every time the button is pushed /query/abcd is executed. anyway the end result is here http://qsorder-k3it.rhcloud.com (the search results return collapsible link buttons)

Comment: You could, in theory, do a fetch-once thing where you cache the first time you fetch...  Just store the results in an object, so when you first load you have `var queryCache = {}` and then when you fetch the results of, say, query abcd you do something like `queryCache['abcd'] = {{results}};`.  When you initially go to load your data you just do a check to see if you already have the results of the query cached, and if not send the ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

i don't believe you can use `href` tag with url in `remote data` in bootstrap ,

you can use `data-tab-url=""` like the folloiwng example :

https://github.com/LeaseWeb/bootstrap-remote-data#L79